# Invalid Property Value de CSS

Tags: css

estoy haciendo un curso de desarrollo web online, y hay una parte en donde hay que hacer un botón y necesito poner la propiedad `Padding`, pero cuando la pongo me dice `Invalid Property Value`. Aquí el código del botón:

```
.boton{
background-color: var(--secundario);
color: var(--blanco);
padding: 1rem, 3rem;
margin-top: 3rem;
font-size: 2rem;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: .5rem;
width: 90%;
text-align: center;
```

}

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Me parece que la coma está de más, prueba así: `padding: 1rem 3rem;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por que esa no es la forma de declarar los distintos valores que un padding puede o debe de usar.

Entonces debes pasar de esto:

```
padding: 1rem, 3rem;
```

A esto:

```
padding: 1rem 3rem;
```

Es decir los valores solamente van con una separación de un espacio en blanco entre ellos.

Entendiendo que con lo anterior, esta indicando:

- paddings superior e inferior con una medida de 1rem
- paddings derecho e izquierdo con una medida de 3rem

**Referencias**

- [sintaxis del `padding`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#paddings)

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta. Error de aprendiz.